# Positioning header items using CSS only

Tags: css, positioning

I've been asked to change the layout of this charity website:

http://antidotemarketing.com/youthlife/

I need to place the nav up the top, then the logo underneath, then under that the white box containing the slider and main content.

This must be done using CSS only.

So far I've had difficulty getting the same results in both Chrome and FF... I haven't even checked IE yet. How would I go about positioning the logo in the middle of the nav and the main content box with some adequate spacing (say 20px top and bottom)

One more issue: I can't absolute position the logo because when people log in to wordpress, the header that wordpress injects into the top messes up the spacing of everything.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: not sure if this can be accomplished entirely with just CSS and no absolute positioning, it partly depends on the element locations in the HTML - as far as I can see there isn't even currently a logo (I may be missing something blindingly obvious though!)

Comment: @Jason "How would I go about positioning the logo in the middle of the nav and the main content box with some adequate spacing (say 20px top and bottom)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I finally understand what you are after. Try adding the following styles:

```
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#login #logo {
  position: relative;
}
#page {
  margin-top: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, I tried this last night, but it still didn't work. The positioning was still off when I logged in and got the top wordpress navigation. Question, what was "#login #logo" supposed to do? Thx.

Comment: #login is an ID given to the <body> tag on the WordPress login page. So it is targeting the #logo ONLY on the #login page, and in this case is essentially attempting to cancel the styles added to the regular/global #logo. Maybe try setting top to 0px for that target as well?

Comment: I managed to fix it myself, and since your answer lead me closer to the solution, you get the tick. Thanks Jason!